# What are those stars?

Tags: rebel-galaxy-outlaw

What are those stars before the name of the sector (green arrow marking them)?

[image: stars]

Answer (score 2):

It means you are currently wanted in both of those systems, so entering them will lead to an attack from that system's law enforcement.

Comment: I have been playing and going thru those systems frequently and never had problem with police. Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: I couldn't find much. Only the tip sheet (https://rebel-galaxy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Rebel-Galaxy-Outlaw-Tip-Sheet.pdf) and this reddit post (https://www.reddit.com/r/RebelGalaxy/comments/cskscv/how_do_i_reduce_my_wanted_level/). Sadly, neither of them are comprehensive.

Comment: I assume you pass through the systems quickly, rather than lingering in them for a while?

Comment: No, I make missions, buy and sell products. Even the police scan for contraband and never gave me any trouble.

Comment: Then you may be wanted by a different faction that isn't the law.